# How to share allure report to stakeholders?

Tags: webdriver-io, allure

I have generated the allure report from my webdriverio framework and configured the report in jenkins.
How can I share the allure report from  jenkins to stakeholders?

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the question.

There are several ways to make this happen:

1. You may provide a link to the Jenkins job which contains the report but, usually, stakeholders don't want to dive into CI. Or they don't have the necessary credentials.
2. You may download and archive and send it. In case there are many tests in the suite, the archive might be massive. That's also an issue.

In case you need to share reports often, I would recommend trying Allure TestOps: it's an Allure Report-based management tool providing an extremely flexible report and dashboard sharing opportunities.